# Facebook text field detection

Tags: facebook, text, field

i just want to ask if there is an api for facebook to detect any text field, be it status update text field or comment text field or any other.

Comment: I mean that suppose that you are creating a standalone application to post a comment on your status bar of facebook wall. So before starting writing you should first check if this is a text field or not ( where one can type anything). So my problem is how we can check if the clicked field is a text field or not. Is there any facebook api for this to check?

Comment: Checking for a text field?! it's **your** application! of course there will be a text field if you added it! I'm still not getting you...

Comment: @ifaour Thanks for keeping patience for me. Actually the scenario is that i want to launch my application once user clicks on any facebook text field, be it status field or comment field. So there must be a facebook api for this which i can include in my application to detect the text field. I hope you have got a clear picture this time. Sorry for causing so much trouble to you.

Comment: Basically i want to use it with javascript and i am very new to it.

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking for your application to get notified when a user does an activity on Facebook (outside your App) like writing a status message or a comment **AND** even more, when he focuses on those fields!

Well, for the later that's absolutely **not** possible **yet** you can still receive *some* "updates" when a user does certain activities by subscribing to the [Real-time methods](http://192.168.1.254/) Facebook provides.